# What does Sharding means from Database Design Perspective?

Tags: database, database-design, sharding

What is the concept of Sharding from Database Design perspecitve ?

Comment: It's roughly equivalent to "pain, pain, pain". But if you must, there is a ton of info on percona.com . In particular, I recommend http://www.percona.tv/performance/baron-schwartz-high-performance-mysql-from-a-boring-architecture-ppc-2009

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992988/what-is-sharding-and-why-is-it-important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitioning the key space across a cluster of DB servers to distribute the service load and promote scalability of the overall system.

Comment: And a good/detailed article on sharding: http://www.codefutures.com/database-sharding/

Answer (score 1):

Well you could start by reading the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharding) on it, and perhaps the [Hibernate Shards](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/shards/reference/en/html/) documentation. If you then have a more specific question, then ask that.

> Horizontal partitioning is a design
>   principle whereby rows of a database
>   table are held separately, rather than
>   splitting by columns (as for
>   normalization). Each partition forms
>   part of a shard, which may in turn be
>   located on a separate database server
>   or physical location. The advantage is
>   the number of rows in each table is
>   reduced (this reduces index size, thus
>   improves search performance).

Comment: This seems to equate sharding with horizontal partitioning, which is misleading. Sharding is breaking up the db into multiple instances; it involves issues with replicating shared state, migrating shards to load-balance, etc. Partitioning is on a per-table basis, and often does not involve multiple instances.