# How should I partition this table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

i have plan to create a analytic's table. Monthly 1 million records approx can be insert to the table. help me better way of optimizing and also fetch records fast way. 
Alternatively i have planned to split the table monthly (Running a cron on server to create table) all insertions will insert rows to respective month table. 
Is this better way to design the tables.

Please advise on database design

Comment: have in mind that databases are meant to parse through large amounts of data

Comment: Showing us the table definition might help: but assuming you're adding analytics records, the most obvious is to [partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html) it against the date created column, either by year or by month/year - but if you create a table for each month/year then you'll hit problems the instance somebody wants a quarterly or annual summary, or a comparison with this month last year

Comment: `code` CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `webanalytics_mm_yy` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `companyid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `visits_count` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `referal_source` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `source_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'This based on source give the name',
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(128) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=63 ;

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Sharding the database. More information can be found here [importance of sharding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992988/what-is-sharding-and-why-is-it-important)

and approaches towards [MySQL sharding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541421/mysql-sharding-approaches). Hope this helps.